# Bash Parse XML to comma separated list

Tags: xml, bash, csv, xpath

How do I return a comma-separated list of the ids, please?

```
<nodes>
 <node>
   <id>1</id>
   <name>idbread</name>
 </node>
 <node>
   <id>2</id>
   <name>idbutter</name>
 </node>
</nodes>
```

expected output

```
1,2
```

I attempted to use XPath, but concat returns only the first value.

> xpath node.xml "//nodes/node/id/text()" 2>/dev/null

returns

`12`

Comment: Where does that `xpath` binary/script come from? The only one I [found](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xpath.1p.html) does not have the syntax you're using.

Comment: @fredrik: OP is probably doing something like this `xmllint --xpath  "//nodes/node/id/text()"  node.xml` but on my system it returns `12`. Version: `xmllint: using libxml version 20904`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk how do you come to that conclusion when he states in the question which command he is running?

Comment: @fredrik: it's just my guess, he might provide only a part of the real command he's using. In any case, he has to make this question more clear to get an answer.

Comment: Maybe OP should tell us which command he's using....

Comment: @mri.o you could use `echo $(sed -n 's:<id>\(.*\)</id>:\1, :pg' file)`

Comment: @sergio: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Hi @fredrik, I am using a Mac, xpath is in it by default, I didn't have to install anything extra to run:  xpath node.xml "//nodes/node/id/text()" 2>/dev/null

Comment: @sergio, I am trying as much as possible not to use any other external library to do this, I wil accept your suggestion if you post it as an answer. It works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler option, using `xidel` which supports xpath 3.0:

```
xidel -s node.xml -e "string-join(//nodes/node/id/text(),',')"
```

Comment: Accepting this as it looks a lot cleaner

Answer (score 4):

You can use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) for this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/nodes/node[1]/id" -m "/nodes/node[position()>1]" -v "concat(',',id)" input.xml
```

This outputs the value of the first `node/id` node and then outputs the following `node/id`s separated by a comma. The output is as desired.

- The `sel` option chooses the *Select/Query* mode of xmlstarlet
- The `-t` indicates the start of an "XSLT template"
- The first `-v` option outputs the value of the XPath expression
- The `-m` option creates a `for-each` over the XPath expression
- The second `-v` option outputs the value of the XPath expression relative to the context value of the `for-each`